# How to drill down a report from a RDLC by clicking any where in the row

Tags: jquery, click, row, rdlc, drilldown

### In RDLC reports we can open a  drill down report only by clicking the text in a row.

### *How to open the drill down report by clicking any where in the Row?*

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr").click(function (event) {
            var a = event.target.firstChild;
             if (a != null) 
                 if (a.localName == "a") 
                      a.onclick();
        });
 });
```